# Getting Wi-Fi AP information in Python

Tags: python, linux, wifi

How can I get wireless information of a Wi-Fi AP? (SSID, Channel, Tx-power, RSSI, ...)

I am currently doing by parsing `iwconfig` output, but I want to do it "in the right way."

Comment: That's the "right way" on Linux.

Comment: You'll probably have to write your own module to work with python - and it will only work on a linux machine.  You'll have to write another module for each OS you want to support.

Comment: I'll only add to KevinDTimm's answer that it's better not to create standalone module for each OS, but to use `platform` module to detect currently used OS. It let you to get portable code. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks guys, but I'm not intended to port the code to other OSes.

Comment: @TazeT.Schnitzel: I can't believe that parsing another programm's output is *the* way nor the *best* way to do it...

Comment: It's the UNIX way though... write programs that use other programs and communicate via text streams.

Comment: @TazeT.Schnitzel: Yes, that's the way with utilities, but I prefer opening a file instead of a process. I think it's more efficient... Or at least it seems to me so!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little bit googling got me [Python Wifi](http://pythonwifi.wikispot.org/) I never used it myself. Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

you can get wireless statistics from /proc/net/wireless

However, if you need iwconfig's functionality which uses iwlib. You can use iwlib via ctypes or through the a python wrapper python-iwlib.

http://git.fedorahosted.org/git/?p=python-iwlib.git;a=summary

Comment: `/proc/net/wireless` doesn't give SSID &c. only statistics. Also I forgot to say that interfaces are in AP mode and don't appear in that "file."